# Grails app is not being loaded only in IE9: what must I check?

Tags: javascript, html, grails, internet-explorer-9

I'm developing a Grails project which is using some JS code. It runs perfectly in `Google Chrome (v34.0.1847.116 m)` and `Mozilla Firefox (v28.0),` but it simply does not run/start in `IE (v9.0.23).` I just have a blank screen.

According to many previous answers on SO community, I should be checking some meta tags which I'm using, but it's not running successfully anyway. There goes my code!

page.gsp, used as main layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html class="win firefox firefox2 gecko gecko2" lang="br">
<!--[endif]-->

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="A nice Title"/></title>
    <r:require modules='core'/>
    <g:layoutHead />
    <r:layoutResources />    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">bla bla bla<g:navbar /></div>
        <g:menu menuKey="1"/> <!-- a taglib which builds a dynamic menu -->

        <div id="content">
            <g:layoutBody />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer"><div class="container">bla bla bla</div></div>
    <r:layoutResources/>
</body>
</html>
```

home.gsp, a simple view to be loaded in the layout above.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="page" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>A simple content here</h2>              
</body>
</html>
```

I'm loading all my JS and CSS resources using `ApplicationResources.groovy` but I don't have any JS error according my Firebug. After all, what else could I check or what features/functions' success must I asure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html class="win firefox firefox2 gecko gecko2" lang="br">
<!--[endif]-->
```

to (properly close the else comment)

```
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html class="win firefox firefox2 gecko gecko2" lang="br">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: GOD BLESS YOUR NEXT 99 GENERATIONS

Comment: I suspect you were going a little insane.

Comment: @VictorFS Looks like the comment sprung out from the bottom of the heart. :)

Comment: I just had the same problem today... Some things never change!